# Javascript, push object to multidimensional array (using Node.js and Cheerio)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, multidimensional-array

I've checked out the other answers to this question, but still think i'm a bit stumped.  I'm using Cheerio to scrape URLS and some other basic information, then scraping those URLS to scrape some more information.  That's all working fine, but i'm having trouble making it into a nice, structured, 'multidimensional' array to export as a JSON file.

I'm creating Objects and pushing them to the array thisBlog.

```
var titles = {
                        blogTitle: blogTitle,
                        profDesc: profDesc,
                        numFollowers: numFollowers,
                        pageTitle: [],

              };


                        thisBlog.push(titles);
```

That works fine.  This is the other Object i'd like to add to the array.

```
var hypestats = {
//Select stats using CSS selectors.
          error: false,
          pageTitle: pageTitle,
          uniqueVisit: uniqueVisit,
          dailyVisits: dailyVisits,
          dailyRev: dailyRev,
          siteWorth: siteWorth,
          alexaRank: alexaRank,
          reach: reach,
          server_location: server_location,

 }
```

At the moment i'm using 
    'thisBlog.push(hypestats);'

But this simply appends the array.  Ideally, i'd like the hypestats Object to create a multidimensional array within the pageTitle array of the titles object, and therefore push to that.  That way, the corresponding Hypestats information is within the correct object.  I hope this makes sense, does anybody have any advice?

**Edit**
I've been tinkering with my code and applying the advice from commenters, is this what the array should look like?

```
  {
     "index":20,
     "blogInfo":[
        {
           "blogTitle":"Style Scrapbook",
           "profDesc":"This is my life, my style, what I love and what inspires me!",
           "numFollowers":150604,
           "hypeStat":[
              {
                 "error":false,
                 "pageTitle":"Stylescrapbook.Com -  Website Report",
                 "uniqueVisit":"11,954",
                 "dailyVisits":"37,176",
                 "dailyRev":"$39.81",
                 "siteWorth":"$15,006.30",
                 "alexaRank":"37,564",
                 "reach":"0.00454%",
                 "server_location":"5"
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

Comment: Did you try just `thisBlog[0].pageTitle.push(hypestats);`

Comment: You can assign `hypestats` to the `pageTtitle` property: `titles.pageTitle = hypestats;` or, since `titles.pageTitle` is an array, you can push to that: `titles.pageTitle.push(hypestats);`

Comment: Hey, for both of these, I received the error: 'Object #<Object> has no method 'push''. Is this because i've already pushed titles to the array thisBlog? (Edited as I submitted too early..)

Comment: @Brian Glaz , I have amended my code, does the edited above look right?